# CLion Compiler Setup

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, ide, clion, jetbrains-ide

I am just getting started with C++ and CLion IDE. I got this error after watching a YouTube video that showed how to get started on CLion. All I did was try to add GCC to CLion as the compiler for C++. Nothing else at all.

I have GCC version 7.5.0 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04)

I've only been programming for about 3 months on HTML CSS & JS so this error is way over my head. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Below is my error and a link to a screenshot

```
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (project):
  The CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:

    GCC

  is not a full path and was not found in the PATH.

  Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
  variable "CXX" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to the full path
  to the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/dominic/CLionProjects/untitled1/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/dominic/CLionProjects/untitled1/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".

[Failed to reload]
```

[Cmake List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHTGl.png)
[image: Screenshot of my ERROR]

Comment: Most likely you don't have `g++` package installed.

Comment: Can you show your CMakelist?

Comment: @FWeidinger I added another screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Use full path to compiler or add the gcc path to PATH if you want to used just `gcc`.

I guess that if you specify C compiler as `/usr/bin/gcc` (or `/usr/local/bin/gcc` if you installed it there) and C++ compiler as `/usr/bin/g++` in Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Toolchains everything should work.

Mind that Linux is case-sensitive OS and GCC executable is `gcc`.